# Error: rxjs/operator/debounceTime has no exported member 'debounceTime'

Tags: rxjs, angular6

I'm migrating from angular 5 to angular 6. When I make npm run build, I'm it is throw to the console the following error:

> error TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/PrjNET/Elevation3/FW/4.00/Mainline/Framework/Development/Client/ElevationJS/ngcore/.tmp/node_modules/rxjs/operator/debounceTime"'
>   has no exported member 'debounceTime'.

I'm importing `debounceTime` as follows:

```
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operator/debounceTime';
```

Any one knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just need to change the import from this:

```
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operator/debounceTime';
```

to this:

```
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: It's not working for I have anuglar 7 and ngBootstrap 4.x.x